# How do I deal with multiple setState called in the wrong order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let’s imagine a simple component run where the user clicks on a button that shows a popup (`setState(P)`) and that causes both an HTTP (`setState(H)`) and WebSocket (`setState(W)`) server to respond with other data to be shown in the popup. Note that `onClick`, `onHTTPResponse` and `onWSResponse` are simple prop event handlers passed to the component which call `setState`:

```js
onClick:         --setState(P)-->
onHTTPResponse:  ---setState(H)-->
onWSResponse:    ----setState(W)-->
```

Now let’s imagine another run where WebSocket is faster than the HTTP response:

```js
onClick:         --setState(P)-->
onHTTPResponse:  ----setState(H)-->
onWSResponse:    ---setState(W)-->
```

Problem with this run is that the WebSocket `setState(W)` depends on the data returned by the HTTP response, hence it depends on `setState(H)` — `setState(W)` must occur after `setState(H)`.

How would I deal with such situation?

Edit: it seems from the responses that I didn’t explain my problem clearly. `onHTTPResponse` and `onWSResponse` handlers are called with the **response** of each. This is the API I have available. I need to solve the `setState` call order from the usage perspective.

Note also that the idea of these prop handlers is that they’re called at *unpredictable* times. The same example could be made with subscribing to an event emitter for whichever data. So answers that involve async/await or promises don’t really make sense: I’m dealing with an event emitter kind of API.

Comment: Are you familiar with await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await? It allows you to wait for HTTP response before proceeding with whatever you want to do. Basically you want to `await fetch(...)`.

Comment: Have you try to use setState CallBack ? something like that. setState(P, () => { seState(H, {setState(W)})})

Comment: A minimal code example would clarify things better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aysnc await function with await in front of onHTTP function and onWebSocket function. Note that you need to put the code you want to run first above the one you want to run later. Example,

```
await onHTTP()
await onWebSocket()
```

They second one will only run when the first one is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call them in the same order that you described?

If sending a message via WebSocket needs data from HTTP request you can wait for the request from HTTP and call send a message via Websocket afterwards.

Just an example;

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const exampleSocket = new WebSocket(
  "wss://www.example.com/socketserver",
  "protocolOne"
);

export default function App() {
  const [httpData, setHttpData] = useState(null);
  const [socketData, setSocketData] = useState(null);

  const onClick = () => {
    fetchData();
  };

  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("yourAPI")
      .then(response => {
        // Examine the text in the response
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          sendMessage(data);
          setHttpData(data);
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Fetch Error :-S", err);
        setHttpData(err);
      });
  };

  const sendMessage = data => {
    exampleSocket.send(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    exampleSocket.onmessage = evt => {
      // listen to data sent from the websocket server
      const message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
      setSocketData(message);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Send request
      </button>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(httpData)}</div>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(socketData)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited the question with an edit at the bottom. The event handlers return the response.

Answer (score 0):

use setState callback

```
this.setState(p, () => this.setState(H, () => this.setState(W)))
```

`setState` callback will be triggered with updated state values, so no need to use async/await.

Answer (score 0):

Since my question was rather unclear I decided to post a more generic one without using React (but pure JavaScript). It seems that using observables is a way to solve this problem. More details are posted in this other question: [How to deal with race conditions in event listeners and shared state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196788/how-to-deal-with-race-conditions-in-event-listeners-and-shared-state)