# How to deal with race conditions in event listeners and shared state?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling, race-condition, event-listener

I have 2 event listeners that operate on the same shared data/state. For instance:

```js
let sharedState = {
  username: 'Bob',
  isOnline: false,
};

emitter.on('friendStatus', (status) => {
  sharedState.isOnline = status.isOnline;
});

emitter.on('friendData', (friend) => {
  if (sharedState.isOnline) {
    sharedState.username = friend.username;
  }
});
```

My problem is that these events are emitted at any order. The `friendData` event might come in before the `friendStatus`. But `friendData` does something with the data returned from `friendStatus`. In other words: I need the event handler for friendData to execute **after** friendStatus, but I don't have this assurance from the event emitter perspective. I need to somehow implement this in my code.

Now of course I could simply remove the `if (sharedState.isOnline) {` from the `friendData` listener and let it run its course. Then I'd have a function run after both handlers have finished and somewhat reconciliate the shared state dependencies:

```js
emitter.on('friendStatus', (status) => {
  sharedState.isOnline = status.isOnline;
  reconcileStateBetweenUsernameAndIsOnline();
});

emitter.on('friendData', (friend) => {
  sharedState.username = friend.username;
  reconcileStateBetweenUsernameAndIsOnline();
});
```

Problem is that this reconciliation function knows about this specific data dependencies use case; hence cannot be very generic. With large interconnected data dependencies this seems a lot harder to achieve. For instance I am already dealing with other subscriptions and other data dependencies and my reconciliation function is becoming quite large and complicated.

My question is: is there a better way to model this? For instance if I had the assurance that the handlers would run in a specific order I wouldn't have this issue.

**EDIT**: expected behavior is to use the sharedState and render a UI where I want the username to show ONLY if the status isOnline is true.

Comment: (F)RP and observables can do a lot here, but it's unclear what exact behaviour you expect here and what the `sharedState` is even used for, so it's hard to write a specific answer.

Comment: "*I can only show the username returned by `friendData` if the latest `friendStatus` emitted had a value of `isOnline` equal to true*" - and if the `isOnline` value is false, what do you want to show then? Always `"Bob"`? Or the last username that you had received before going offline? Or just nothing? Or something else? Also, it is unclear when and by what code the `sharedState` is actually getting displayed, and whether the event handlers will need to trigger that displaying as well.

Comment: Btw, no, this is not a race condition, this is just a state machine that might or might not have different results depending on the order in which events were received.

Comment: @Bergi I edited with a more specific requirement. But the example is a purposely contrived one to showcase the issue I'm having with race-conditions. I think you're right that observables might help; in that sense I think you're hinting at a `showUsername` property that observes both `username` and `isOnline` and changes accordingly when they change? Akin to computed properties in MobX https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html - I guess then my question would be how to achieve this in vanilla JS

Comment: Yes, just like a computed property or an observer depending on the two properties. And `reconcileStateBetweenUsernameAndIsOnline` is in fact exactly how you'd do that - it is describing the specific computation of `showUsername` from the state input.

Comment: @Bergi makes sense! If you care about showing an observable example I can approve your answer. I can also do this if you don't.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @Bergi's answer in the comments the solution I was hinting seems to be the most appropriate for such case. Simply let the event-handlers set their own independent state, then observe on the values changing and write appropriate logic based on what you need to do. For instance I need to show a username; this function shouldn't care about the order or have any knowledge of time: it should simply check whether the `isOnline` status is true and if there's a username. Then the observable pattern can be used to call this function whenever each dependency of the function changes. In this case the function depends on `status.isOnline` and `friend.username` hence it will observe and re-execute whenever those values change.

```js
function showUsername() {
  if (status.isOnline && friend.username != '') return true;
}
```

This function must `observe` the properties it depends on (status.isOnline and friend.username). You can have a look at RxJS or other libraries for achieving this in a more "standard" way.